# Rails change html element attribute in link_to

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, attributes, link-to

I'm creating a Previous Page button. This is my button:

```
<li>
<%= link_to "Previous Page", titles_path(:page => @previous_page), class:"button big previous" %>
</li>
```

If page is 0, it should be disabled. My new button should be like this:

```
<li>
<%= link_to "Previous Page", titles_path(:page => @previous_page), class:"disabled button big previous" %>
</li>
```

I mean, I should use if-else in link_to, and according to the if-else my code should change class of my button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional as Tony suggested, but Tony's approach is a bit flawed because `0` is not false in Ruby. Try this

```
= link_to 'Previous Page', titles_path(page: @previous_page), class: "#{(@previous_page == '0')  ? 'disabled' : ''} button big previous"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I marked Tony's answer as the solution because of timing. But thanks anyway.

Comment: The logic is flawed there, don't forget to change it.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operator `? :` to insert something directly into class string:

```
<li>
<%= link_to "Previous Page", titles_path(:page => @previous_page), class:"#{@previous_page != '0' ? '' : 'disabled'} button big previous" %>
</li>
```

or simply use `<% if %> <% else %>`:

```
<% if @previous_page != '0' %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to "Previous Page", titles_path(:page => @previous_page), class:"button big previous" %>
    </li>
<% else %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to "Previous Page", '', class:"disabled button big previous" %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```